# Windows service configuration file

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm currently developing a basic windows service with a configuration file (`servicename.exe.config`), the default configuration file you access in a Visual Studio project properties. This service installs and runs correctly, however I am unable to find the configuration file of the installed service.

Read/Write code snippet:

```
/// <summary>
/// An idle period between sending warning emails to avoid spamming
/// </summary>
public static short WarningEmailIdleMin
{
    get
    {
        return Properties.Settings.Default.WarningEmailIdleMin;
    }
    set
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.WarningEmailIdleMin = value;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

Project settings image:
[image: Project settings image]

- The service is running under the local system account
- When stopping the service, changing a setting in the `servicename.exe.config` (next to the executable) and starting the service does not change the setting (proving its not pulling the settings from this config file)
- When altering a setting in the service code, stopping and starting the service, the setting has the updated value from the previous run (proving it is being saved somewhere)
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile` points to the above config file

I have looked in the sub-directories of `AppData` in the `default` and `public` user accounts, I have also looked in `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\`

Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT: Added code snippet of save/read

Comment: Can you show the code where you read that setting from the config file?

Comment: Have added more above :) cheers

Answer (score 3):

You are using user settings. These settings are not stored in `servicename.exe.config` next to the executable. I found [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f3e1f68-d19c-4a43-a650-bd4afa9c4593/c-application-settings-where-are-they-stored?forum=csharpgeneral) at MSDN. It describes where user.config is stored and how to get the file path of that config.

Personally I don't think that using user settings is a good choice for windows service which by default runs under local system account (if not set differently). I would suggest to use a local file database (i.e. sqlite or Sqlserver CE etc.) for these settings.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be this file as changing the file and starting the service doesn't use the updated value. Also updating the value in the service itself doesn't update the file.

Comment: Also, if the service is run as a user, the config file does get saved correctly to the users `AppData` folder, but no idea where it stores it for the system user

Comment: These are the reasons to not use user settings :) A colleague of mine has spent some time with user settigs developing a destkop application. It was not working well. It was working when the application was running and I think that also when the application reloaded. But it didn't survive restart of the system. We abandoned this concept and went to using database or custom xml file for user settings.

Comment: I've found user settings to be pretty good for simple stuff in application development, it's just with the windows service using the local system account I want to know where it stores it :)

Answer (score -3):

There should be a web.config file after install, if you installed it correctly on your system.
An installed service should not be in C:\Windows\system32.... it should be in C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Comment: I think you're thinking of web service, I'm working with windows services

Comment: Good point - I've been working with web services recently and that narrowed my view.